# Check for valid vimeo url ios

Tags: ios, regex, vimeo

I want to check for a valid vimeo url

```
  -(BOOL) validateUrl2: (NSString *) candidate2
{


     NSString *urlRegEx2 = @"(https://vimeo.com/(channels/[a-zA-Z]+/){0,1}[0-9]+[?]{0,1}.*$))";

    NSPredicate *urlTest2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx2];

    urlCheck2 = [urlTest2 evaluateWithObject:candidate2];

    return [urlTest2 evaluateWithObject:candidate2];

}
```

I am using above code but it's not working, i guess their is some issue with RegEx, can any one provide me with RegEx to check wether a url is valid vimeo url, basically i want to check wether url contains @"https://vimeo.com/anything".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(BOOL) validateUrl2: (NSString *) urlString
{

    NSString *urlRegEx2 = @"http://.*vimeo\\.com/.*/(\\s|$)";
    NSPredicate *urlTest2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx2];
    urlCheck2 = [urlTest2 evaluateWithObject:candidate2];
    return [urlTest2 evaluateWithObject:candidate2];

}
```

**Edit:** I you just want to check if the URL is like @"https://vimeo.com/anything"

why the check the host?

```
-(BOOL) validateURLWithString: (NSString*)urlString {
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    if ([url.host isEqualToString:@"vimeo.com"])
        return YES;
    return NO;   
}
```

you can also check what is the scheme

```
[url.scheme isEqualToString:@"https"]
```